# MediaPositionState shows incorrect currentTime

Tags: android, reactjs, html5-audio, webapi, mediasession

So, here is the problem. I'm using audio html5 element in my react project.
The typical flow for problem is:
the song is playing.
User presses pause on some time(let's say that time is 1.20).
User locks the phone.
After several minutes user unlocks his phone, presses "Play" button and here what happens:
The mediaPositionState count current time as previous(1.20) PLUS current time of the audio, instead of counting just current.
This extra 1.20 is remaining even when changing songs.
I've tried to control it in useEffect below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const audioEl = audioRef.current;
    if (audioEl) {
      audioEl.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateTime);
      audioEl.addEventListener('loadeddata', updatePositionState);
    }
    return () => {
      if (audioEl) {
        audioEl.removeEventListener('timeupdate', updateTime);
        audioEl.removeEventListener('loadeddata', updateTime);
        updatePositionState();
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

but it works normally only when user is in focus with audio.

Also I have following code:

```
  function updatePositionState() {
    if (navigator.mediaSession?.setPositionState) {
      navigator.mediaSession.setPositionState({
        duration: audioRef.current?.duration ?? 0.0,
        position: audioRef.current?.currentTime ?? 0.0,
      });
    }
  }
  const createMediaSession = (state: AudioStateType) => {
    if (navigator.mediaSession) {
      navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: state.currentSongName,
        artist: state.currentArtistName,
        album: state.currentAlbumName,
        artwork: [
          {
            sizes: '300x300',
            src: `http://storage.musicstream.app/cover/${state.currentAlbumCoverId}`,
          },
        ],
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function () {
        dispatch({ type: 'resume' });
        updatePositionState();
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function () {
        dispatch({ type: 'pause' });
        updatePositionState();
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', function (details) {
        dispatch({ type: 'manual_update_time', time: details.seekTime });
        updatePositionState();
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => {
        return 0;
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => {
        return 0;
      });
    }
  };
```

I don't know how to normally describe the problem, let's assume that mediaposition messes up when user swipes out the MediaSession notification.
I will provide more code if you ask.
Also I provide the screenshots(despite I tried to force the problem similar one occured: it shows time as the end of track).

[image: current song time]
current song time

[image: current song time is okay when paused]
current song time is okay when paused

[image: current song time is messed when playing]
current song time is messed when playing

Adding updateTime function by request
It is just for updating state in react.Context

```
const updateTime = () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      dispatch({ type: 'update_time', time: audioRef.current.currentTime });
    }
  };
```

Also, the full reducer looks like this(I don't think it would be helpful):

```
function audioReducer(state: AudioStateType, action: Action): AudioStateType {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'fetch_and_play': {
        play(action.songData?.currentSongId).then(() => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'play',
            songData: {
              ...action.songData,
              length: audioRef.current?.duration,
            },
          });
        });
        return state;
      }
      case 'play': {
        createMediaSession({ ...state, ...action.songData });
        return { ...state, ...action.songData };
      }
      case 'pause': {
        pause();
        return { ...state, songIsPaused: true };
      }
      case 'resume': {
        resume();
        return { ...state, songIsPaused: false };
      }
      case 'update_time': {
        return { ...state, currentTime: action.time };
      }
      case 'manual_update_time': {
        if (audioRef.current) {
          audioRef.current.currentTime = action.time;
          return { ...state, currentTime: action.time };
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      }
      default: {
        return state;
      }
    }
  }
```

I made a codesandbox, where you can see my problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wiles-87qi1?file=/src/App.js
In order to truly understand please use an android phone

Comment: can you share `updateTime` function ?

Comment: @b3hr4d, added to the question block

Comment: Reducer should be Pure function you should use action before reducer for dispatch and other staff.

Comment: I understood what you said, but could you provide an example for at least 1 case? Should I have a seperate function for stuff I'm doing in `case` block? And also, will it influence the MediaPosition?? Or is it just an advice??

Comment: ok ill make an example as the answer. I think it can resolve many problems.

Comment: It seems like a Chrome issue. Do you mind filing a bug at crbug.com/new so that the team can address it?

Comment: Wow, thank you for request, of course I'll try filing a bug!

Comment: For the record, here's the bug URL: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1167926

Answer (score 1):

Reducer should be Pure function, use action before reducer for dispatch and other staff:

Action.ts

```
const fetchAndPlay = (currentSongId) => {
   play(currentSongId).then(() => {
        createMediaSession({ ...state, ...action.songData });
        dispatch({
          type: 'play',
          //just pass data u need to show or you want rerender them
          length: audioRef.current?.duration,
      });
    });
}
```

Reducer.ts

```
function audioReducer(state: AudioStateType, action: Action): AudioStateType {
switch (action.type) {
  case 'play': 
       return { ...state, length:action.length, playing: true};
  ...
}
```

In your component just call this action :

```
fetchAndPlay(songId)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that leaving a simple function and calling it here and there in different components is a good idea unless it is a hook, but creating a hook for this little logic is unnecessary. Morevover, i've made it so complex because of async action which happens in `play` function, saw similar approach here, on stackoverflow. I'm sure this won;t deal with mediaPosition, cause I cold do it much uglier with props and the result would be the same.

Comment: Are you using redux?